# Present View Controller is opened on ViewController's View or On Window ?

Tags: ios

I want to know that the present view controller is opened on view or on window.
What is `self` representing in this Code.

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: self is the ViewController that will present the imagePicker. The file you are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is presented from the view controllers `view`.

Note that if the view controllers `view` is not full screen (i.e. it's a child view whose frame is only the bottom half of the screen) then you should not present from that controller. Instead, you should present from the parent controller (or, more generically, the root view controller).

Comment: Hi Wain i just upvote your answers actually i had these problem in my project where i am child view contains navigationcontroller.view. when i do present view controller it takes time and also gives warning like,Warning :-Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

it is view for window when you set window of view controller size small you can check

Answer (score 0):

**UIViewController** is **super** **class** of all **UIViewController** so we can access the all available method of UIViewController.
presentViewController is **method** of **UIViewController** so we can access this method to present new view controller in our view controller.
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]; in this method self represent  own object to access this method. due to inheritance we can access this method.